# Magento admin login very slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

since 1 month, when I login to my Magento dashboard, it's very very slow. It took 30 seconds to log me!
Before that, I was log in 4-8 seconds.

I'm running Magento CE v1.9.2.4
I did not install new module since 2 months... Nothing new .. I guess

I just don't know why. Here is a screenshot of Chrome dev. TTFB is over 40seconds!

[image]

[image]

The frontend works fine, and the dashboard too, after login.
Is someone can help me, someone else in my case?

**EDIT**
   - I tried to disable Admin Notification, but there no effect

Thank you!

Comment: You can disable notification in adminhtml in system configuration. Because notification request by curl magento commerce site for check `updates ` ,`path`, `news ` and other information. But you will can't get message in adminhtml.

Comment: And you can show you php log? and magento log in directory `var/log/exception.log` and `var/log/system.log`

Comment: @Naumov I tried to remove Notification, but it's not better...
And in those logs, nothing interesting :(

Comment: You configuration for develop set enable log, and you need error_reporting E_ALL in php

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for a slow admin panel.

To prevent Magento from retrieving notifications from third-party sites you could disable the admin notifications module by running the following command from shell.

First login with SSH and make sure you are in the right folder (i.e. /var/www/domain.com/web).

Run the following command to unload the admin notifications module:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminNotification
```

Next is to check if the Magento cache settings are all enabled. You can check this by running the following command:

```
php bin/magento cache:status
Current status:
                        config: 1
                        layout: 1
                    block_html: 1
                   collections: 1
                    reflection: 1
                        db_ddl: 1
                           eav: 1
         customer_notification: 1
            config_integration: 1
        config_integration_api: 1
                     full_page: 1
                     translate: 1
             config_webservice: 1
```

If you see some having the value of 0 then you have to fix that by running:

```
php bin/magento cache:enable
There is nothing to change in cache status
```

If cache is set and you still experience a slow Magento site then make sure your MySQL settings are optimal and that you use the right hardware. Fast CPU, plenty of RAM and use SSD disks.

Comment: This answer is about Magento 2. Question was about Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

Disable observer-event in local.xml. 1 element can be the rss time out limits:

```
 <adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <adminnotification>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </adminnotification>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue relates to the Magento notifications

Under: **System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Modules Output** simply set **Mage_AdminNotification** to `Disable`.

1. Save
2. Log out
3. Log back in